# So many requests in 1 second for updating one specific data record

Tags: mysql, database, request, updating

There are 1000+ requests comes to update just single specific record in 1 or less then 1 sec. How can we deal with this, every single request is **very important**.
*

> Suppose, 1 sec = 1000+ requests comes for updating just one specific record

Comment: How can "every single request" be "very important"?  All of them but the last one get completely overwritten and discarded by those that follow.  Perhaps best to keep track of the latest value somewhere, and periodically commit it to the database.  I suppose it depends somewhat on how often the value will be read/retrieved.

Comment: Its very important every request because my app is for quick buying & selling product. Every single request comes to buy a product. So newer request will always buy that product again. There are just 1 quantity for that product. so every user request comes to buy that product, becomes the owner of that product. 
 I have user owner_id field, and when new request comes i am sending message that old owner that new user has purchased that product.

Comment: @makashtekar . . . And you are saying that thousands of people are buying the same product each second?  That is faster than bids are processed on even busy electronic trading markets.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes you are right. They are buying faster like this. May be more then i suggested numbers once Active user Goes up. :)

Answer (score 2):

1,000 updates per second is quite feasible on modern computers. However, so many updates on a single record pose problems. You can design hardware -- say using in-memory tables or solid-state disks -- that can implement this.

However, often this type of structure is needed to keep something up-to-date. You can instead insert a new row into the table and have any application that needs the "current value" just fetch the most recent row. Of course, if you are using the values as well as overwriting them, that introduces even more contention for the row.

Comment: @makashtekar which is why GL suggests an alternative design

Comment: i think problem is with database

It something happens like this
Suppose, there are 10 request ,
When server executes 1st request , in the mean time 2nd another request comes, Now, Server is clever it will not put requests in the queue. So server will start executing the 2nd request too. While server starts executing 2nd lets say 1st request proceed to 30% and 2nd request to 10%. Now, 

Here, every request updates just one specific row. 
So lets say when request reaches to 70% its updates the record in database, and when reaching to 90% it inserts new records in another table like feed. cont..

Comment: It is fine when older request process completion ratio(30%) is Greater then 2nd request (10%) .. But i think somehow this process is being alternate with any kind of internal query process length time. So it sometime may be happens OLDER request completion rate < Newer request completion rate. And when this happens OLDER request becomes wrong and output comes which is not expected by me.

Comment: @Strawberry if you like to see real practical issue i can show it to you.